# Messenger extension in not working in webview

Tags: webview, facebook-messenger-bot

After whitelisting my domain, I try to access messenger extension to get the user ID, it failed with error :

> Messenger Extensions are not enabled - could be "messenger_extensions"
>   was not set on a url, the domain was not whitelisted or this is an
>   outdated version of Messenger client

I tried the messenger on google chrome and firefox same error is appearing. messenger_extensions is set to true and domain is whitelisted; I confirmed.

Why is it bring that message?

Comment: Can you run `curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?fields=whitelisted_domains&access_token=$ACCESS_TOKEN"` in your terminal to confirm your domain is whitelisted? What response does it give?

Comment: I did that it's; It is working in Mobile Phones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to access it through a browser? If so that may be why you are having issues.

Try access the url through the messenger app on your phone. This will iFrame in the web page and you will have access to the MessengerExtensions sdk.

Not sure how you are supposed to be able to log within messenger though. I did something like this to test it out

```
window.extAsyncInit = function() {
// the Messenger Extensions JS SDK is done loading
    MessengerExtensions.getUserID(function success(uids) {
        // User ID was successfully obtained. 
        var psid = uids.psid;
        console.log("psid", psid)
            $('.error').html(psid)

    }, function error(err, errorMessage) {      
        // Error handling code
        console.log(err, errorMessage)
        $('.error').html(errorMessage)
    });    
};
```

Comment: Everything is working fine in mobile phones but not on Computer browsers. How does facebook expect the browser users of the bots which use webview to use the bots? Is there any workaround?

Comment: I don't believe you are supposed to. For instance, browsing via the messenger app makes the assumption that user has given permission to profile information - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/user-profile

Answer (score 0):

You should add `image_url` to the message. This field isn't required, but if you don't include it, the shared message will only work within a mobile context.

Example:

```
var messageToShare = {
    attachment: {
        type: "template",
        payload: {
            template_type: "generic",
            elements: [{
                title: "Title",
                image_url: "https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg",
                subtitle: 'A shared list from Tasks',
                default_action: {
                    type: "web_url",
                    url: "your_url",
                    messenger_extensions: true,
                    webview_height_ratio: "full",
                    fallback_url: "fallback_url"
                },
                buttons: [{
                    type: "web_url",
                    title: "title",
                    url: "your_url",
                    messenger_extensions: true,
                    webview_height_ratio: 'full',
                    fallback_url: "fallback_url"
                }]
            }]
        }
    }
};
```

Also, with `messenger_extensions: true` you'll need to add `fallback_url: "<your_fallback_url_here>"` to make it work.